# Laravel 4.2 Creating a grouped list dropdown from the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am able to create a select element using:

```
$team = DB::table('team')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('team')->with('team', $team);
```

and then in my form I have:

```
{{Form::select('team', $team) }}
```

this produces output that looks like:

```
<select id='team'>
    <option value="1">Jane Doe</option>
    <option value="2">Dan Kennedy</option>
    <option value="3">Zack Glickman</option>
</select>
```

Which is wonderful.

However, I would like to organize the drop down by departments and team members so that I would get the following output:

```
<select id='team'>
    <optgroup label="Marketing">
        <option value="1">Jane Doe</option>
        <option value="3">Zack Glickman</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Sales">
        <option value="2">Dan Kennedy</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Obviously this would require a join between the departments table and the team table but I am not sure how I can get the query to build the nested arrays that laravel requires for grouped lists as shown in the [Laravel Drop Down List Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need subarrays. Your Team variable contains elements like Marketing and Sales. And each elements contains your persons with name and the id.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing.

```
$departments = DB::table('departments')->get();
$data = array();

foreach($departments as $department) {
    $team = DB::table('team')->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
    $tdata = array();

    foreach($team as $t) {
        $tdata[$t->id] = $t->name;
    }

    $data[$department->department] = $tdata;

}

return View::make('team')->with('team', $data);
```

This works but I was hoping that there was a more eloquent way to do this using Laravel's ORM or Query Builder but I can't figure out how.

Anyway on to the next problem!